# How to access computed variable inside computed initializer in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

In my swift 3 program shown below, I want to access computed variable 'darkColor' inside computed initializer. But swift 3 compiler giving me an error: **instance member 'darkColor' cannot be used on type 'LoginViewController'**

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: BaseViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // FIXME: - computed variables
    private var darkColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(hex: 0x0083C5, alpha: 1)
    }

    // FIXME: - create views / computed initializers
    lazy var textEmail: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "Email"
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
        textField.textColor = darkColor     // here I'm getting error that "instance member 'darkColor' cannot be used on type 'LoginViewController'"
        textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.delegate = self
        return textField
    }()

    let emailUnderline: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = darkColor     // here I'm getting error that "instance member 'darkColor' cannot be used on type 'LoginViewController'"
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    // FIXME: - life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Comment: you will need a instance to your class to actually create that computed variable, maybe use `class var` or move it outside of the class to make it a constant, then you can access it

Comment: @Tj3n - I think you are right. I have to create another class for constants

Comment: @Tj3n - yes you are right. I verified your answer. Please post your answer to answer section so that I can mark it as accepted

Comment: I forgot that you can actually use `self.darkColor` also, i think it would be best choice for you with `lazy` property, for other immediately variable, then will have to use other options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few possible way to use it during computed variable init

1. Use `self.darkColor` for `lazy` variable since it will only get created when access (cant access `self` during initialize of the class)
2. Change to class variable, but this will affect all of the instances of `LoginViewController`
3. Move the `let darkColor {...}` outside the class scope will make it become global constant

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tj3n for giving me hint. I found 4 solutions for this issue. Out of them 3 were from Tj3n.

Solution 1 - Use different class for constants

Solution 2 - Use class var instead of var

```
class var darkColor: UIColor {
    return UIColor(hex: 0x0083C5, alpha: 1)
}
```

Solution 3 - Use static let instead of var

```
static let darkColor: UIColor = {
    return UIColor(hex: 0x0083C5, alpha: 1)
}()
```

Solution 4 - Use self.darkColor for lazy var kind of computed variables.
For e.g.

```
lazy var emailUnderline: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = self.darkColor
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```